# VS 2015: Project not loaded for debugging

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I have solution with about 15 projects. Environment is VS Enterprise 2015 on Windows 10.

While debugging, the breakpoints on some (about 3/4) of the projects show "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document....". While looking for possible reasons for this issue with the breakpoints, I opened the modules window (Debug -> Windows-> Modules) and found that these projects don't show up in the list of loaded modules. Other projects in the solution however are there in the loaded modules list. What could be the reason for the debugger to unable to load these projects?

Comment: Are the projects affected all the same programming language? And is that programming language different than the projects where the breakpoints *are* binding?

Comment: @John, all the projects in the solution, the ones that load and the ones that do not load are C# projects.

Comment: if the modules are not showing up in the modules window, then it is likely that those modules just have not been loaded yet. Once you execute code that is in those modules, those modules should show up.

Comment: @John, one of those projects, which is the project of my debugging interest, does not loads even if it is being executed. If I remember it right, I tried executing the portions of UI that invoke that project but it didn't show up in the loaded modules. I will try again however, and post an update here.

Comment: If someone can point to relevant resources, it would be good to know the criteria for loading of those modules.